# Rails Server does not load after closing terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, terminal, osx-elcapitan

I am trying to run the `rail server` command in terminal on my mac(el captain 10.11.4).  Every time I close the terminal window it results in this:

```
/Users/pinkelephant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2/lib/debug_inspector.rb:6:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/pinkelephant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2/lib/debug_inspector.bundle (fatal)
```

I then can get it to work if I completely reinstall ruby...not ideal. Bundle install does not help either. Any ideas?

Comment: make sure you use the correct ruby version and/or gemset. `rvm list` and `rvm gemset list` should help you check that

Comment: Maybe follow these steps and try running server again: https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.11-el-capitan